# Python df.to_excel() storing numbers as text in excel. How to store as Value?

Tags: python, html, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am scraping table data from google finance through pd.read_html and then saving that data to excel through `df.to_excel()` as seen below:

```
    dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOGL&fstype=ii&ei=9YBMWIiaLo29e83Rr9AM', flavor='html5lib')
    xlWriter = pd.ExcelWriter(output.xlsx, engine='xlsxwriter')

    for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
        df.to_excel(xlWriter, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i))
    xlWriter.save()
```

However, the numbers that are saved to excel are stored as text with the little green triangle in the corner of the cell. When moving over this data to excel, how do I store them as actual values and not text?

Comment: How are those columns coming in with pandas: `print(df.dtypes)`? Might need to run conversions.

Comment: It looks like they are all listed as 'objects'. What do I need to do to run conversions to 'float' or 'int'? I can't find anything about converting to a value before hitting excel.

Comment: Thx for the upvote @gluc7. Re-reading through your question, I think it would be a good idea to edit its title (if possible, not sure, I'm still newish to SO) because the problem wasn't really with the df.to_excel method... And the solutions don't deal with anything specific to exporting to Excel.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider converting numeric columns to floats since the `pd.read_html` reads web data as string types (i.e., objects). But before converting to floats, you need to replace hyphens to NaNs:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfs = pd.read_html('https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOGL' +
                   '&fstype=ii&ei=9YBMWIiaLo29e83Rr9AM', flavor='html5lib')
xlWriter = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
workbook = xlWriter.book

for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    for col in df.columns[1:]:                  # UPDATE ONLY NUMERIC COLS 
        df.loc[df[col] == '-', col] = np.nan    # REPLACE HYPHEN WITH NaNs
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)         # CONVERT TO FLOAT   

    df.to_excel(xlWriter, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i))

xlWriter.save()
```

Answer (score 35):

In addition to the other solutions where the string data is converted to numbers when creating or using the dataframe it is also possible to do it using options to the `xlsxwriter` engine:

```
# Versions of Pandas >= 1.3.0:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_numbers': True}})

# Versions of Pandas < 1.3.0:
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'strings_to_numbers': True})
```

From the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html):

> **`strings_to_numbers`**: Enable the `worksheet.write()` method to convert strings to numbers, where possible, using `float()` in order to avoid an Excel warning about "Numbers Stored as Text".

Comment: This is the actual Solution. Thanks a lot. My dataframe indeed has mixed String and float, so the column was obviously Object. But I still wanted Excel to display the number as numbers

Comment: Answer from the creator of the package himself

Comment: How can this be made to only affect certain columns? I have a column of IDs with leading zeros as strings and another of numerical values.

Answer (score 4):

That is probably because the Data Types of those columns where the warning is showing are `objects` and not Numeric Types, such as `int` or `float`.

In order to check the Data Types of each column of the DataFrame, use [`dtypes`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E52KV.png), such as

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

In my case, the column that was stored as object instead of a numeric value, was `PRECO_ES`

[image: DF dtypes]

As, in my particular case, the decimal numbers are relevant, I have converted it, using [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), to float, as following

```
df['PRECO_ES'] = df['PRECO_ES'].astype(float)
```

If we check again the Data Types, we get the following

[image: DF column changed to float]

Then, all you have to do is export the DataFrame to Excel

```
#Export the DataFRame (df) to XLS
xlsFile = "Preco20102019.xls"
df.to_excel(xlsFile)

#Export the DataFRame (df) to CSV
csvFile = "Preco20102019.csv"
df.to_csv(csvFile)
```

If I then open the Excel file, I can see that the warning is not showing anymore, as the values are stored as numeric and not as text

[image: Excel file without the warning]

Comment: For those using strings call: df_employees[col].astype(pd.StringDtype())

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify that the columns that you're exporting are actually numbers in python (int or float)?

Alternatively, you can convert the text fields into numbers in excel using the =VALUE() function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to python. How do you check if they are actually numbers? I tried the 'type' function but I don't believe it works on variables.  I would also like to try to do most of the work within in python so that the excel workbook is already converted when opened.

Comment: Try `df.dtypes`. If you need to convert, use `pd.to_numeric()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since pandas 0.19, you can supply the argument na_values to pd.read_html which will allow pandas to correctly automatically infer the float type to your price columns...

Here's how that would look like:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(
    'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOGL&fstype=ii&ei=9YBMWIiaLo29e83Rr9AM',
    flavor='html5lib',
    index_col='\nIn Millions of USD (except for per share items)\n',
    na_values='-'
)

xlWriter = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.to_excel(xlWriter, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i))
xlWriter.save()
```

Alternatively (if you don't have pandas 0.19 yet), I'd use a simpler version of @Parfait's solution:

```
dfs = pd.read_html(
    'https://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ%3AGOOGL&fstype=ii&ei=9YBMWIiaLo29e83Rr9AM',
    flavor='html5lib',
    index_col='\nIn Millions of USD (except for per share items)\n'
)

xlWriter = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    df.mask(df == '-').astype(float).to_excel(xlWriter, sheet_name='Sheet{}'.format(i))
xlWriter.save()
```

This second solution only works if you correctly define your index column (in the .read_html), it will fail miserably with a ValueError if one of the (data) columns contains anything that is **not** convertible to a float...

Answer (score 0):

If you want your excel sheet to have string data type do like so:

```
for col in original_columns:
    df_employees[col] = df_employees[col].astype(pd.StringDtype())
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'StringDtype' for Version 0.23.4

Comment: @NikoTumi Hey, were you able to solve your problem. I didnt get time to respond in time but I can help if your code still has an issue