# Excel Copy Using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input excel file with custom data formats , I want to create another excel file with the same data as input bus having 'text' as data format. The reason for this is to preserve the data as some of the alphanumeric data goes null when it is imported directly to table as excel treats them as number based on some of their initial values. I am new to Python , please help me with it.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080999/python-df-to-excel-storing-numbers-as-text-in-excel-how-to-store-as-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python df.to\_excel() storing numbers as text in excel. How to store as Value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080999/python-df-to-excel-storing-numbers-as-text-in-excel-how-to-store-as-value)