# Storing a dataframe to excel as numbers with percent or other formatting

Tags: pandas, dataframe, formatting

I am using the Excelwriter and df.to_excel to store a dataframe to an xls file.  I am using `engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_numbers': True}}` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080999/python-df-to-excel-storing-numbers-as-text-in-excel-how-to-store-as-value).

The dataframe looks like this in Python.  It seems that is a series of strings or text rather than numbers and when you load it into Excel you get warnings saying "The Number in This Cell is Formatted as Text or Preceded by an Apostrophe" so it is considered text in Excel.  If you do a isnumber(A1) you well get false for all cells.

I guess I could just write the dataframe as a bunch of floats, but then I have to format in excel.  Is there any way to write this to excel while preserving the number formatting, as decimals, etc?

The ExcelWriter code is shown below as well

```
       ExpRet    Vol Min   Max  Iter1  Iter2  Iter3  Iter4  Iter5   Iter6   Iter7   Iter8   Iter9  Iter10
FGE      5.7%  16.0%  0%  100%   0.0%   1.8%   3.0%  12.2%  30.4%   43.8%   50.0%   50.0%   50.0%   50.0%
FFI      4.8%   6.0%  0%  100%   0.0%  10.5%  20.3%  33.1%  19.5%    6.2%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%
FRA      4.5%  10.0%  0%   25%   0.2%   0.9%   1.3%   4.7%   0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%
FAR      6.5%   7.0%  0%   25%   0.4%  15.2%  25.0%  25.0%  25.0%   25.0%   25.0%   25.0%   25.0%   25.0%
FCO      7.0%   8.0%  0%   25%   0.1%  10.0%  19.3%  25.0%  25.0%   25.0%   25.0%   25.0%   25.0%   25.0%
CASH     2.5%   0.5%  0%  100%  99.3%  61.7%  31.1%   0.0%   0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%    0.0%
Return                           2.5%   3.8%   4.9%   5.8%   6.0%    6.1%    6.2%    6.2%    6.2%    6.2%
Vol                              0.5%   2.0%   3.6%   5.1%   6.7%    8.2%    9.0%    9.0%    9.0%    9.0%
Sharpe                           0.05   0.67   0.68   0.65   0.53    0.45    0.41    0.41    0.41    0.41
Ploss                            0.0%   3.0%   8.5%  12.8%  18.4%   22.8%   24.6%   24.6%   24.6%   24.6%
Var05                            1.7%   0.5%  -1.0%  -2.6%  -5.0%   -7.4%   -8.7%   -8.7%   -8.7%   -8.7%
Var01                            1.3%  -0.9%  -3.4%  -6.1%  -9.6%  -13.0%  -14.8%  -14.8%  -14.8%  -14.8%
```

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfilename, engine="openpyxl" ,mode='a',if_sheet_exists='replace')
Finaldf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=outsheetname,startrow=1, startcol=0,engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_numbers': True}})
worksheet = writer.sheets[outsheetname]
worksheet['A1'].value=ScenarioName
writer.close()
```